# wcfTestClient Configuration with WSSF in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, wcftestclient, wssf

I am using the WSSF to implement my wcf services project.I want to invoke the service operations using wcfTestClient like general wcf project. I mean if i run the my service form Visual Studio,it should run through wcfTestClient tool.
I can run the service by adding the service location manually in the wcfTestClient tool.but i want to run WcfTestClient from visual studio execution.

How to configure it? Please provide some url's

Answer (score 0):

here is a link to configure the wcftestclient tool to launch in Visual Studio

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wcftoolsteamblog/archive/2010/01/04/tips-for-launching-wcf-test-client.aspx

Comment: @Rickey, thanks for your reply.Your link providing information for only Visual studio WCF projects templates.but i am implementing using WSSF